# Reading Only Words in Text File in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm working on a project for my Visual Basic class in which I'm supposed to read in a file and display the information (employee names and salaries) in a list box.

I have a total of 4 forms. 
The first form doesn't actually display anything, it simply has the menu items to open the file, select any of the other 3 forms, and exit the form.
In the second form (names), only the employee names read in from the file are displayed in the list box.
In the third form (salaries), only the employee salaries read in from the file are displayed in the list box.
The fourth form is basically just like the second and displays the employee names read in from the file.

The problem is, I don't know how to do this so that only certain parts of the file are displayed in the list boxes (names and salaries). Also, in the fourth form I have to ask the user to enter the amount of months that they would like to calculate the salary for the selected employee and then multiply their salary by the number of months entered by the user. I know how to do this, except for how I would go about getting the salary. For example, I'm thinking it would be something like this:

lblTotal.Text = dblSalary * intMonths

But I don't know how to store just the salary of the selected employee in the dblSalary variable?

Here's what code I have written so far, however it's simply opening an open file dialog box when the user clicks File->Open from the main form

```
Public Class Main

    Private Sub OpenFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
        open.Filter = "text files |*.txt|All Files|*.*"
        open.InitialDirectory =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my text file titled employees.txt

```
Steve McGarret  
1500.00
Danny Williams
1300.00
Matthew Casey
1700.00
Kelly Severide
1750.00
```

I hope that's clear, if not let me know and I can try to clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what code you have so far, please.

Comment: The only code I have so far is just to open an open file dialog box, I can post it, but didn't think it was really relevant.

Comment: Also, show what the file looks like... How the data is laid out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I won't post a specific solution, but I'll post the idea of how I would do it...

I would:

1. Create 2 new `List` variables - `Dim Names as new List(Of String)` & `Dim Salaries as new List(Of Double)`
2. Read the text file line by line and, given the file format, each even line will add to the `Salaries` list and every odd line will add to the `Names` list
3. Set each list as the DataSource for the appropriate listbox

Hope this helps and gives you an idea of how to proceed, at the very least.

**UPDATE:**

Given your comment saying you wanted to store the data in a class, you could do something more along the following:

1. Create your Class with the 2 attributes and whatever other methods you need - Call it `EmployeeData`, say
2. Create a `List Of(EmployeeData)`
3. Loop through the text file 2 lines at a time (meaning read in the first line, capture the name, read in the next line, read in the salary, THEN loop)
4. In each loop, once you've captured the data, add a new `EmployeeData` to your list with the 2 pieces of captured information.
5. Write a small bit of code that will extract from your EmployeeData list only the salaries or only the names as a new list that you can use to bind to your listbox as the datasource.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I was looking over some more of the directions and wondered if there was a way to tweak this a little to fit them, we are supposed to create a class with the attributes strName As String and dblSalary As Double, the properties name (any String) and salary (only positive numbers, negative numbers should be set to 10), and this which I'm assuming is a function since it returns something (?) computeSalary(intMonths As Integer) this returns the salary for a selected employee multiplied by the number of months the user would like to calculate the salary for.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to store the information read from the file into those variables that I will be creating inside the class?